# readfile function is printing non-existent number after the contents

Tags: php

I wrote a simple single liner PHP program to output contents of a file. 
The HTML code is:

```
<form action="output.php">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**output.php** file:

```
<?php
echo readfile("text.txt");
?>
```

**text.txt** file:

```
hi hello
```

hexdump of **text.txt** file:

[image]

there is 0000008 in the end but in the utf-8 format i don't think 08 corresponds to the character '8'

But in the browser when i click the submit button the output is:

> hi hello8

I don't know where the 8 came from. how can i solve this issue to print "hi hello" not "hi hello8"

Comment: should i put hexdump of the txt file in the question

Comment: how can i seperate the length of file and contents of file

Comment: The `00000008` that hexdump prints is the length of the file, not anything in it. The first column of a hex dump is the offset in bytes from the start of the file.

Comment: As a side note, this has nothing to do with PHP 5, and you should not be using PHP 5 anyway. It has reached the end of the life and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) returns the number of bytes read on success. So in your case the file contains 8 bytes.

`readfile()` will output the contents of the file, so I assume your mistake here was to assume that it will return the contents and you need to `echo` them yourself, but that is what `file_get_contents()` does

Comment: i used readfile('text.txt') instead of echo readfile('text.txt'). The output was as i expected. so the conclusion here must be that first readfile('text.txt') is executed and it printed the contents of the file and returned the length of file. the returned length was taken back by echo statement and was printed next on screen.

Comment: Correct, the function runs first, and passes the number of bytes to the `echo` which outputs it right after the contents